# Click this image/link to activate a jquery pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
   <div class="btnSection">
     <a href="#" class="split-btn sp-blue"><img src="images/star.png">Save Progress</a>

  </div>
```

I'm trying to get this to work with a jquery popup plugin. The plugin requires you to click a button for the popup to take affect. How can I make my Image/Button activate that jquery?

This is the popup I'm trying to use : http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/

The button is drawn with CSS and then the image is just a little icon to the left.

Comment: raise click event on page load..

Answer (score 1):

```
$("btnSection").click(function () {

    //make the animation for the div to show up
    $(".myDiv").popUp();

});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

you mean like:

```
$("a.split-btn").find("img").click(function() {
    $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
});
```

Updated::
to bind more than 1 images, add same class o all your required images, say "img-class", and do:

```
$(".img-class").click(function() {
    $('element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to bind more than one image to the click event?

Comment: @NoWayIn yes, if your images are wrapped in anchor tag containing class name "split-btn", then same code should work fine

Comment: @NoWayIn see my added answer, did you mean something like that..?